# get unique available combination

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to solve below problem, where I need to get available unique combination in data set

Here is input table having two columns

```
IND, USA
USA, IND
AUS, IND
IND, AUS
UAE, AUS
```

used this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       LEAST(c1, c2) AS c1,
       GREATEST(c1, c2) AS c2
FROM   table_name
```

Got output

```
IND, USA
AUS, IND
AUS, UAE
```

first two  records in output are fine, but third one is not correct because `AUS, UAE` combination dont even exists in input data.

May I know how to fix this in my query ?

expectedoutput

```
IND, USA
AUS, IND
UAE, AUS
```

Comment: Is this one table with two columns, C1 and C2?

Comment: If you don't care whether it is [IND, USA] or [USA, IND], why do you care about [AUS, UAE] vs. [UAE, AUS]?

Comment: @Littlefoot Well AUS, UAE doesn't actually appear in the original table.

Comment: I know, @Tim :) Just asking. No objections to code you wrote, +1.

Answer (score 3):

Using `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LEAST(c1, c2), GREATEST(c1, c2)
                                   ORDER BY c1) rn
    FROM table_name t
)

SELECT c1, c2
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

The strategy here is to assign a row number to each group of records having the same pair of country values.  We report the single pair having the "earlier" first country.

Comment: cant we do it without using least and greatest ?

Comment: @OxanaGrey Well you could replace the `LEAST` and `GREATEST` calls with `CASE` expressions.

Answer (score 2):

A union of an intercept with a reverse except can get you that.

> ```
> create table table_name (c1 char(3), c2 char(3));
> insert into table_name values
>   ('IND' , 'USA') 
> , ('USA' , 'IND') 
> , ('AUS' , 'IND') 
> , ('IND' , 'AUS') 
> , ('UAE' , 'AUS');
>
> (SELECT DISTINCT 
>   LEAST(c1, c2) AS c1, 
>   GREATEST(c1, c2) AS c2
> FROM table_name 
> intersect
> SELECT c1, c2 from table_name) 
> union
> (SELECT DISTINCT 
>   GREATEST(c1, c2) AS c1, 
>   LEAST(c1, c2) AS c2
> FROM table_name 
> except
> SELECT c2, c1 from table_name)
> ORDER BY c2 DESC
> ```

| c1 | c2 |
| --- | --- |
| IND | USA |
| AUS | IND |
| UAE | AUS |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=9491dff647f753185cec384d580d26f5)*

Comment: its prey cool,  but am not able to understand the logical thinking used in this query to reach to the output. Can you please what was your logical thought before writing your query in answer ?

Comment: I mean to say, what was your logical thought behind shuffling data and taking selective dataset to get the output ?

Comment: Simple really. 1) how can I get the oddball (UAE, AUS) alone, hence the EXCEPT. 2) How can get the others without the reverse oddball, hence the INTERSECT. To be fair, my first instinct was to use row_number like Tim. But adding a solution that's too similar to another is kinda lame. So I had to use other sql tools for this puzzle.